# Angular array filter is not working on a list of string

Tags: filter, angular10, angular-arrays

I have an array of string, and want to filter out a particular string after some operation. But, it seems I am doing something wrong there.

```
this.displayUser.followers.filter(userId=>userId !== this.loggedUser.userid);
```

Here, followers is an array of string -> `string[]` and upon some action (say, unfollow); I want to remove the logged user's id from the displayed user's followers list.
However, this filter operation does not seem to work.

On the other hand I tried using splice which is working perfectly fine.

```
this.displayUser.followers.splice(
      this.displayUser.followers.findIndex(userId=>userId === this.loggedUser.userid)
 ,1);
```

I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong in the first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) does not change the array it performs its action on, but returns a new array with values that passed the condition.
In order to use `.filter` and have the result saved, you can do:

```
this.displayUser.followers = this.displayUser.followers.filter((userId) => userId !== this.loggedUser.userid);
```

This will remove all entries where `userId === loggedUser.userid`.

[`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) on the other hand manipulates the array it performs its actions on, hence you will immediately see the results as expected.